# How is 'options ath10k_core cryptmode = 1-software' an error?

Tags: linux, wifi-driver, modprobe

I have made a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` called `ath10k_core.conf`. Its only contents are `options ath10k_core cryptmode = 1-software`. To my surprise, `sudo dmesg | grep ath10k` reports that this is an error

> [   13.956647] ath10k_core: `' invalid for parameter` cryptmode'
> [   13.956657] ath10k_core: unknown parameter '=' ignored
> [   13.956661] ath10k_core: unknown parameter '1-software' ignored

Yet, `sudo modinfo ath10k_core` reports this line

> parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)

which I interperate as `1-software` being a valid argument to the `cryptmode` parameter.

Clearly, I am wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Clearly... First of all why? Is this still related with your probable issue of perception? Generally speaking we don't need to change/tweak anything with Atheros chipsets. In any case you're very wrong when trying to apply those parameters, you have spaces where there shouldn't be any and the parameter is just the number.

Comment: So my main suggestion is stop messing around with things you don't understand .

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's the only way to learn. But you're right that I may no longer require it.

Comment: For the record and as always, it should have been `options ath10k_core cryptmode=1` . There's no harm in trying and you can easily reverse it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
options ath10k_core cryptmode=1
```